# Calculation of cumulative sums according to the descending order of total values of data

Tags: spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFHMr.png)

I want to perform the operation in Spotfire.
When using the all-previous function to find the cumulative sum, the cumulative sum is calculated in ascending order of the letters of the item.

I want to calculate the cumulative sum in Sales descending order and the ratio to the total sum.
(* Raw data is monthly sales volume and Sales is the result of Pivot monthly sales volume and summing them up by item )

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.